# Plot a timeline of discrete events

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot discrete events over time. I tried `stripchart()` but I am not happy with the result and I'm looking for a ggplot implementation of this type of figure. Can someone suggest a ggplot solution?

[image]

Here is what I did so far as a minimal example:

```
a = c("no", "yes", "no", "yes", "no", "maybe", "no", "yes", "maybe") 
b = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) 
mydf = as.data.frame(cbind(a,b)) 
mydf$a = as.factor(mydf$a) 
mydf$b = as.numeric(mydf$b)

stripchart(b ~ a, data=mydf, pch = "x", 
           main="Sequence of fun",
           xlab="Time",
           ylab="Fun?",
           xaxt="n")
```

Comment: off topic: If you'd remove `cbind` and call `mydf <- data.frame(a, b)` then `a` would be a factor and `b` would be `numeric` right away.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you consider ugly about the existing figure and what an improved figure would look like? Right now, this question is too broad and primarily opinion based, which is off topic for SO.

Comment: @JanBoyer: A more positivistic way to express my question would be „I‘m not satisfied with my current solution and I‘m looking for alternative - preferably ggplot - solutions for this type of plot“.

Answer (score 3):

One (hopefully *fun*) way to do that:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(emo)
#install.packages("ggthemes")
#devtools::install_github("hadley/emo")

set.seed(54467805)

dat <- data.frame(
  fun  = sample(c('yes', 'maybe', 'no'), 24, replace = T),
  time = 1:24
)

dat %>%
  mutate(fun = fct_relevel(fun, c("no", "maybe", "yes"))) %>%
  mutate(txt = fct_relabel(fun, ~c(ji('poo'), ji('thinking'), ji('happy')))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = fun, label = txt)) +
  geom_text() +
  ggthemes::theme_par() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = 'Time', y = 'Fun?')
```

[image]